# Minimum number of vertices needed to construct a graph.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am given following problem as homework.

Let $G$ be a vertex obtained by attaching a pendant vertex $x$ to $K_n$ and $n\geq 3$. I need to show that I need at least $2r-2$ vertices to add to $G$ to obtain a graph $H$ so that the resulting graph has two vertices with eccentricity $r+1$ and rest with eccentricity $r$. also, $G$ induced in H$.  I assumed the following cases.

It is clear that $diam(G) = 2$. 
Let $x$ be a pendant vertex attached to $K_n$ and $vx\in E(G)$ for some $v\in V(K_n)$.
Let $H$ be an $r$-ASC embedding graph in which graph $G$ is induced.
We have following two cases here depending upon eccentricity of vertex $x$ in $H$.

**Case (a)** $x$ is a diametral vertex of $H$, i.e. $e_H(x) = r+1$.

Proved by me.

**Case (b)** $x$ is not a diametral vertex in $H$, i.e. $e_H(x) = r$.

In this case, we have following subcases depending whether $K_n$ contains a diametral vertex or not.

***Subcase (i)*** $K_n$ contains a diametral vertex, say $y$.
Then there exists vertex $z$ in $H$ such that $d_H(y,z) = r+1$.
Let $P: y=y_0,y_1,\ldots,y_{r+1} = z$ be a diametral path. Then $P_1$ contains
at least $r-1$ vertices ($r+2-3 = r-1$, atmost three from $G$)

***Subcase (ii)*** $K_n$ does not contain a diametral vertex.

***How to move forward in the first subcase?*** Any hint or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot for the help.